# How can I make a barchart that compares the sum of two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, sum, bar-chart

I would like to draw a barchart that would compare the total revenue of the year of two different columns: 'Revenue-Small-Seller-IN', 'Revenue-Small-Seller-OUT'.

I've already managed to add a row that sum the two columns' revenue, with this: 
`pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.3f}'.format
sums = result.select_dtypes(pd.np.number).sum().rename('Total') 
result.append(sums)`

my dataframe looks like this:

```
Rev-Small-Seller-IN   Rev-Small-Seller-OUT      Year-Month  Revenue             

       139.120               0.000                2010-12   139.120

        22.200               0.000                2010-12    22.200

       278.730               0.000                2010-12   278.730
```

Here's a screenshot if it isn't very clear (sorry, I know you guys don't like these):[top rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znm98.png), [last rows with total row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOxQ7.png)

And here's what I would like it to look like:[Barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWDge.png)

In advance, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`df.loc['Total', ["Rev-Small-Seller-IN", "Rev-Small-Seller-OUT"]].plot(kind='bar')`

Comment: "KeyError: 'the label [Total] is not in the [index]'" :/

Comment: Is `Year-Month` your index name??

Comment: yes it is! Should I try to put 'Total' as the index instead? Is it possible as it is a row and not a column?

Comment: It just replaced the index `Year-Month` by 'Total` with still the dates in each row...